# How can I use webrotate 360 in my image gallery?

Tags: magento2, gallery

Hi I'm trying to add the **webrotate360** to my image gallery. Webrotate needs an id or a class to target, so I thought to open up **gallary.phtml** in

`magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view.`

```
<?php /** * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */ /** * Product media data template * * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery */ ?>
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">

<div data-role="loader" class="loading-mask">

<div class="loader">
<div class="360img"></div>

<img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>" alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...') ?>">
</div>
</div>
</div><!--Fix for jumping content. Loader must be the same size as gallery.-->
<script>
    var config = {
            "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
            "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
            "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
            "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height'); ?> },
        thumbBarHeight = 0,
        loader = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder"] [data-role="loader"]')[0];

    if (config.navtype === 'horizontal') {
        thumbBarHeight = config.thumbheight;
    }

    loader.style.paddingBottom = ( config.height / config.width * 100) + "%";</script><script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
                "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
                "options": {
                    "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/nav"); ?>",
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/loop"))): ?>
                        "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/loop"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"))): ?>
                        "keyboard": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/arrows"))): ?>
                        "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"))): ?>
                        "allowfullscreen": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> "width": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>",
                    "thumbwidth": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width')): ?>
                        "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
                        "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect"); ?>",
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"))): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
                    "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navdir"); ?>"
                },
                "fullscreen": {
                    "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav"); ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop")): ?>
                        "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir"); ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/navarrows")): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype"); ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows")): ?>
                        "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?> "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect"); ?>"
                },
                "breakpoints": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBreakpoints(); ?> }
        }
    }</script>
```

And add `<div class="360img"></div>`.[image: backend webroatate target class]

This does not give me the result I want because the `<div class="360img"></div>` is not even showing up, while using inspector.
I am able to target the class above the **'gallery-placeholder'** which is **'product media'**. But then the gallery is gone which is expected though. So to conclude my question, How can I place my **webrotate360** as the first image of my gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Check with this value: `.column .media`

For more ref check: http://www.webrotate360.com/products/cms-and-e-commerce-plugins/plugin-for-magento.aspx?section=Features